# Apply site theme to control panel

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

I have developed a theme. It is working fine when I applied to a site(organization). But when click go to control panel,it is applying liferay classic theme to control panel, But my requirement is that, if navigate to control panel from site 1, it should apply site 1 associated theme to control panel.If navigate to control panel from site 2,it
Should apply site2 associated theme to control panel. Please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Default Control Panel Theme" in Portal Settings -> Display Settings